# how to check CLOB is having prolog or not

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am having a clob column that is having xml data. Here i have written a function that validates data is xml or not. I have used "xmldata := XMLTYPE(xml);". it is working fine.

I have tried with couple of inputs like

```
SELECT isXML('<testfdjkasksdf</test>') FROM DUAL; O
SELECT isXML('<test>fdjkasksdf</test>') FROM DUAL; 1
```

Everything looks good for me until we had an issue reported that it is not checking for prolog. user want to see prolog  before XML data. how can i throw an error or message if input xml is not having prolog.

My Function is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isXML(xml CLOB)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
xmldata XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
xmldata := XMLTYPE(xml);
return 1;
EXCEPTION
when others then
return 0;
```

END;
   /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isXML(xml CLOB)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  xmldata XMLTYPE;
  xml_parse_error EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(xml_parse_error, -31011);
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    xmldata := XMLTYPE(xml);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN xml_parse_error THEN
      return 0;
  END;

  BEGIN
    xmldata := xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>' || xml);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN xml_parse_error THEN
      -- xml already had prolog
      xmldata := null;
  END;

  IF xmldata is not null then
    -- xml did not already have prolog
    return 0;
  END IF;

  return 1;
END;
/
```

The first `XMLTYPE(xml)` is the one you have now; if that gets an XML parsing error (ORA-31011) then it's immediately rejected.

The second prepends a dummy prolog. If `xml` already has a prolog then this fails; without the error being caught you'd see:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00209: PI names starting with XML are reserved
```

If that error is generated then `xml` did have a prolog and `xmldata` is set to null. If that error is *not* generated then `xml` did *not* have a prolog and `xmldata` will contain the XML document.

Then I'm checking whether `xmldata` is null. If it is then it errored and there was a prolog so it's OK. If it is not null then there was not originally a prolog, which we want to treat as an error.

```
SELECT isXML('<testfdjkasksdf</test>') FROM DUAL;

ISXML('<TESTFDJKASKSDF</TEST>')
-------------------------------
                              0 

SELECT isXML('<test>fdjkasksdf</test>') FROM DUAL;

ISXML('<TEST>FDJKASKSDF</TEST>')
--------------------------------
                               0 

SELECT isXML('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><test>fdjkasksdf</test>')
FROM DUAL;

ISXML('<?XMLVERSION="1.0"STANDALONE="YES"?><TEST>FDJKASKSDF</TEST>')
--------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                   1
```

Comment: thq for response. I have updated with ur function then tried SELECT isXML('<test>fdjkasksdf</test>') FROM DUAL; it gave me 1 but i want it to be 0. since it is not having prolog <?xml version="1.0"?>. is that way it works.

Comment: @user1268890 - when I run `SELECT isXML('<test>fdjkasksdf</test>') FROM DUAL;` with that function code I get `0`. You tagged the question with both 10g and 11g; which exact version are you using? I tested on 11.2.0.3, and [it works as expected on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d815a/1) which is 11.2.0.2.

Comment: Thank you very much it is working. Iam using 11g express edition.